# Defining an abbreviation style in glossaries that shows only long version first and short version afterwards

Tags: formatting, glossaries, acronyms, glossaries-extra

I want to define a new abbreviation style in `glossaries-extra` that fits the binomial nomenclature of species like this:
First use (only the long version): *Escherichia coli*
Second use (only the short version): *E. coli*

Here is an example with the abbreviation style `long-em-short-em`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}  
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}  
\setabbreviationstyle[species]{long-em-short-em}  
\newabbreviation[category={species}]{ecoli}{E.~coli}{Escherichia coli}  
\begin{document}  
First use: \gls{ecoli}\par  
Second use: \gls{ecoli}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Which works fine except of the repetition of the short version in parentheses after the first reference. I've tried to find a solution in the [User Manual](http://packages.oth-regensburg.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) (chapter: 13.1.2), but i don't understand exactly how these commands work. The example in the [Beginners Guide](http://ctan.mirror.norbert-ruehl.de/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf) (p. 4ff.) doesn't work in my document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New abbreviation styles are defined with `\newabbreviationstyle`, as mentioned in the `glossaries-extra` [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.pdf) (Section 3.5, page 112, unfortunately without many details).

There are a few aspects to consider. Formatting abbreviations is done by redefining `\CustomAbbreviationFields`. The first use of an abbreviation is formatted with the key `first` that is set within `\CustomAbbreviationFields`. Starting from the `long-short` example the short form can be removed by deleting `\glsxtrparen{\protect\glsfirstabbrvfont{\the\glsshorttok}}` (the short form in parentheses) as well as `\protect\glsxtrfullsep{\the\glslabeltok}` (the separation between the long and short form).

Secondly, the abbreviation style needs to be set to `regular` for the changes to take effect, using the following code within the second argument of `\newabbreviationstyle` (the first argument is the style name):

```
\renewcommand*{\GlsXtrPostNewAbbreviation}{%
    \glssetattribute{\the\glslabeltok}{regular}{true}}%
}%
```

Third, the fonts can be defined in the third argument of `\newabbreviationstyle`, by defining `\glsfirstlongdefaultfont` for the first use and `\glsabbrvfont` for the subsequent uses.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}  
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\newabbreviationstyle{custom-firstnoshort}% label
{% setup
\renewcommand*{\CustomAbbreviationFields}{%
name={\protect\glsabbrvfont{\the\glsshorttok}},
sort={\the\glsshorttok},
first={\protect\glsfirstlongfont{\the\glslongtok}},%
firstplural={\protect\glsfirstlongfont{\the\glslongpltok}},%
plural={\protect\glsabbrvfont{\the\glsshortpltok}},%
description={\the\glslongtok}}%
\renewcommand*{\GlsXtrPostNewAbbreviation}{%
    \glssetattribute{\the\glslabeltok}{regular}{true}}%
}%
{% fmts
\renewcommand*{\glsfirstlongdefaultfont}[1]{\textit{##1}}%
\renewcommand*{\glsabbrvfont}[1]{\textit{##1}}%
}
\setabbreviationstyle[species]{custom-firstnoshort}  
\newabbreviation[category={species}]{ecoli}{E.~coli}{Escherichia coli}
\begin{document}
First use: \gls{ecoli}\par 
Second use: \gls{ecoli}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The command `\renewcommand*{\glsfirstlongdefaultfont}[1]{\textit{##1}}%` turns also my other abbreviations outside the category "species" in italic. Is there an option, which only sets the one category in italic?

Comment: Maybe `\glsfirstlongfont` would work, or `\glsabbrvemfont`. For the 2nd one you need to change also the font specification in `first=` and `firstplural=`. Or define a custom command, or maybe `\textit` inside `first=` would also work (I don't have time to test it now but I'm sure it is possible).